# AngularJS $apply sometimes doesn't trigger to update $scope values in the html tag within {{}}, when using the click event in hightchart.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a strange problem.

I use AngularJS and HighChart, when I try to define a click event by hightchart:

```
                        point: {

                            events: {

                                click: function () {         
                                    $scope.currentRunId = XXX;                             
                                    $scope.showDetailModal();
                                }

                            }

                        }
```

And in function showDetailModal I define:

```
    $scope.showDetailModal = function (){



      $scope.$apply(function(){
          console.log($scope.currentRunId);     
      });

      $("#detailModal").modal('show');

    }
```

I find that although the console can log the value of $scope.currentRunId correctly, the binding value in the html sometimes can be updated, sometimes can't:

```
  <div  class="modal fade" id="detailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModal" aria-hidden="true">
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{currentRunId}}</h4>
  </div>
```

the value in the h4 tag sometimes is correct sometimes is null sometime is a cached value.. Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $scope.showDetailModal inside your controller. so you don't need to call digest/apply method there. You will have to call digest or apply if you change anything out of angular scope. So correct code will be:

```
 point: {

                        events: {

                            click: function () {         
                                $scope.currentRunId = XXX;                             
                                $scope.showDetailModal();
                                $scope.$digest();
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

OR

```
point: {

                        events: {

                            click: function () {         
                              $scope.$apply(function(){
                                 $scope.currentRunId = XXX;                             
                                 $scope.showDetailModal();
                               }); 

                            }

                        }

                    }
```